# Google Analytics - Single Page Site - Click Tracking

Tags: jquery, google-analytics, event-tracking

The site in question is http://getstefan.com

Its a single page portfolio site and I have tried using jQuery to add Google Analytics click tracking to every anchor tag on the site hoping to track where people are clicking. There is a script that adds a unique ID to each anchor on the page, so I set a timeout to make sure and place the Google Analytics click tracking after the id has been assigned. Like so:

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
        setTimeout(loadOnClick,8000)
    });

    function loadOnClick() {
        jQuery('a').each(function(){
            jQuery(this).attr("onclick", "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'anchor', 'click', '" + jQuery(this).attr('id') + "']);" );
        });
    }
```

Which results in building a link like so:

```
<a href="http://getstefan.com/wp-content/themes/inc v2/downloads/CV-StefanHinck-FR.pdf" id="cv" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'anchor', 'click', 'cv']);"></a>
```

Everything looks good.
Problem is that when I look at my analytics, the only clicks registered are labeled "untitled"

Anyone know what im doing wrong here?

Comment: just a note: your site has bookmarking and url issues, AJAX is like anything else in programming its only nice if used right.

Comment: I didnt do the AJAX, nor am I capable, could you explain a little further the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First**
Your anchors don't have an ID assigned, so the code is doing exactly what it should be reporting 'undefined' as the value for something that doesn't exist.
For example

```
<a class="entry-link" href="http://getstefan.com/portfolio/interior-design-logo/"></a>
```

**Second**, don't use the timer.

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
        setTimeout(loadOnClick,8000)
    });
```

should be replaced by

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        loadOnClick();
    });
```

so you don't have to wait 8 seconds and can just assign everything when the DOM is ready.

Comment: If I use this loadOnClick(), does that mean that when the user clicks the anchor, it will actually add the google tracking at the moment of click? Please excuse me, I am not much of a programmer...

Comment: For your first question, I don't see the ID being assigned. Have you seen it assigned? Your loadOnClick function attempts to READ the ID, it doesn't do anything to ASSIGN it.

Comment: Your 'loadOnClick' function is not triggered by a click. You have it triggered based on time, which is why I suggest you change it to the document/ready implementation so you don't have to wait. That being said, you still need to manually assign a unique id to each anchor (<a>) you want to track.

Comment: Your right, they are not being assigned now. Very strange as last night they were. I have changed the jQuery to now pull the id from the parent element.

Comment: Yes thank you, your right it makes more sense now to simply load it on ready as apparently the id's are not being assigned to the anchor tags at all.

Answer (score 2):

Might I suggest a slightly more compact version?

Also, this doesn't refer to the anchor's `id`, it uses the `href`, might might be suitable for basic scenarios (i.e., if two links direct the user to the same URL, you won't know what link contributed what number of visits.) If you do add `id`s to your anchors, just replace `.attr('href')` with `.attr('id')`.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('a').click(function() {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'anchor', 'click', jQuery(this).attr('href')]);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Babak Naffas's good post, remember that a `_gaq.push` call initiates an HTTP request.

If your server is speedy, it's entirely possible that the link the user clicked loads before the Google Analytics call does, in which case nothing's going to get tracked.